# How to use a single button click event to call a method with different parameters

Tags: c#

I have multiple button click events:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Procedure(1);
}

private void button16_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Procedure(16);
}
```

However, I want to achieve something like this:

```
private void button[i]_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Procedure(i);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Winforms, there is a call to `InitializeComponent()` in the class constructor.

In that method (it will take you to the form designer if you put the mouse cursor on the method and right click > goto definition or F12) you will see how events are hooked up:

```
button1_Click += button1_Click...
```

You can simply subscribe the buttons click event to your `Procedure` method.

```
button1_Click += CallToProcedure;
```

How do you work out which button was clicking then? You simply get it off the `sender` argument in the parameter:

```
private void CallToProcedure(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button btn = sender as Button;
    int i = Convert.ToInt32(btn.Name.Replace("button", string.Empty));
    Procedure(i);
}
```

Comment: Did you copy and paste my answer ?

Comment: @user3185569 its extremely childish downvoting my answer. Next time explain how to use it. And for the record No, `btn` is standard Hungarian notation I've used for almost 20yrs now and I too rely on standard button naming and simply replace "button" when I work with arrays of buttons. Everything else is standard too.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the parameter you're passing to your button (`i` in your example) in the Button's [`Tag`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.tag(v=vs.110).aspx) property then use something like this:

```
var senderButton = sender as Button;
if (sender != null)
{
    Procedure((int) senderButton.Tag);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can rely on the naming, then simple:

```
private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button btn = sender as Button;
    int i = Convert.ToInt32(btn.Name.Replace("button", ""));

    Procedure(i);

}
```

Answer (score -1):

use button.Tag property, is designed for such cases.

read is doc / MSDN