# Programming buttons in C# without the use of toolbar

Tags: c#, user-interface, button

I am fairly new to C#. Basically what I am trying to do is build "buttons" with actual code rather than any of the drag and drop tools. I use Visual Studios and have only worked with a console application but I want to move to more visual GUI style programs and every tutorial that I could find focuses on using Visual Studios toolbar system.

I should mention that I am not necessarily looking for someone to layout the entire process for me, just a pointer in the right direction.

Comment: There are people marking your question down and voting to close. It would help if you read the documentation that explains how to ask a good question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Jeremy's answer is a good way forward. If you can understand that the VS drag-and-drop designer is not doing anything special other than writing code for you in the `Form1.designer.cs` file. You just have to learn to write that kind of code yourself.

Answer (score 2):

> I am trying to do is build "buttons" with actual code rather than any of the drag and drop tools.

Create a new WinForm project (Full .Net not core). You will be presented with a blank Form1.

In VS20XX open the ToolBox and drag/drop a control on to the Form, eg a Button.

Select the control and press F4 to bring up the properties. Set its Name for example to btnClickMe.

Now double click the control or the form to see the "Code Behind". In Winforms, Forms are classes that derive off a base class (which implements all the extra functionality to make the class a Form).

In this code view, scroll up to where you see `InitializeComponent()` and right click > GoTo Definition.

Here you will see there is actually a hidden file called Form1.Designer.cs and that has all the code you created by drag/dropping controls.

You can add your own "design-time" code preferably in the `Form_Load()` method or after the `InitializeComponent` line/call in the Form's Constructor method.

Also check how you can subscribe events to **controls you create dynamically**, eg:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/37365431/495455